# Action bar not shown in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I'm using Android Studio for the first time and can't manage to make the `ActionBar` show when I run the app. Here's what I have so far:

My Activity *MainActivity.java*

```
package xeniasis.mymarket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

it's layout *activity_main.xml* (nothing there)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="xeniasis.mymarket.MainActivity"></RelativeLayout>
```

and the menu with one item *activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="xeniasis.mymarket.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_update"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_update"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/update_app" />
</menu>
```

Do I need something else in order to show the `ActionBar`?

**EDIT**

here is the app theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what style did you define in the manifest xml?

Comment: @UğurB i edited my question

Comment: go with the `Toolbar`..`ActionBar` is deprecated now..

Comment: @Akshay I added a `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in my layout but it still doesn't appear

Comment: Use `AppCompatActivity` and `ToolBar`.

Comment: @jaydroider I just did and the app crashed

Comment: okay, I had to change the theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` and now it works

Comment: Check my answer also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Use `AppCompatActivity` with `ToolBar` as per Material Design.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        // Find the toolbar view inside the activity layout
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        // Sets the Toolbar to act as the ActionBar for this Activity window.
        // Make sure the toolbar exists in the activity and is not null
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    // Menu icons are inflated just as they were with actionbar
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

> `activity_my.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <!-- Layout for content is here. This can be a RelativeLayout  -->

</LinearLayout>
```

> Add this in `Style.xml`.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
  <!-- This would set the toolbar's background color -->
  <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  <!-- android:textColorPrimary is the color of the title text in the Toolbar  -->
  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
  <!-- android:actionMenuTextColor is the color of the text of action (menu) items  -->
  <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
  <!-- Enable these below if you want clicking icons to trigger a ripple effect -->
  <!-- 
  <item name="selectableItemBackground">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
  <item name="selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">?android:selectableItemBackground</item> 
  -->
</style>

<!-- This configures the styles for the title within the Toolbar  -->
<style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
</style>
```

> menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miCompose"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_compose"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Compose">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miProfile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Profile">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: works perfectly! one last question though! why is my only item shown in the overflow icon? since there is actual space in the `ToolBar`

Comment: Add multiple items in your menu.xml. I have edited check.

Comment: what if I only want one item? :)

Comment: Then it will only show one item in overflow menu. Look if you want to add more item to overflow menu make it multiple. if not want keep it single. Appreciate Up-vote and accept answer if it helps thanks :).

Comment: Up-vote it also so it will be helpful to others thanks :).

Comment: btw, adding `android:orderInCategory="100"` made the item appear normally

Comment: @XeniaSis `orderInCategory`is just for sequence, if set same value for all menu item then they will apper in sequence as they are in menu file

Answer (score 0):

you must call you actionBar almost similar to how you would inflate a view and remember to use tool bar

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)this.findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
      if(toolbar!=null){

      }
      //getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

      getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic__actionbar);

      // Set up the action bar.
      final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
      if (showTabs) actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

      // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
      // primary sections of the activity.
```

Comment: where should I add add the `ToolBar` layout?

Comment: @XeniaSis add toolbar in your layout file

Answer (score 0):

In the design view, click the eye icon (view options) and select "Show Layout Decorations"