# Error inflating CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, layout, androiddesignsupport, coordinator-layout, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to add a bottom sheet to my layout, so I place all my fragment's layout inside a CoordinatorLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/myOriginalLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:clickable="true">

       ....
       ....

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It keeps on crashing though when I try to inflate the layout, stating `Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: Have you added `AppCompat` ?

Comment: yes.. `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.+"` but it doesn't help

Comment: Post your `Gradle` above.

Comment: ok.. I've added it

Comment: Give a try by changing this `buildToolsVersion '24.0.0-rc3'` add dash.

Comment: still no luck... could it be perhaps due to the fact that my activity extends Activity instead of AppCompatActivity ?

Comment: Is it showing error Project Run Time  or while creating Layout ?

Comment: it just crashes when inflating the layout as depicted in the post (`Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`)

Comment: You mean while designing your `Layout` at that time it is throwing you in design mode `(Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout)` Right.

Comment: nope.. I added a screenshot of what the layout designer in android studio shows me. 
The app is able to run though, it only crashes when I get to that fragment (more specifically - in onCreateView when trying to inflate the layout)

Comment: Have you tried from `Activity` to `AppCompatActivity` ? If not then Try and Check.

Comment: I have tried , but it creates another crash if I do that (change Activity to AppCompatActivity) :
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: Try with my answer may be will solve that.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this `theme` by Changing from `Activity` with `AppCompatActivity`.

```
    <style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo">
    </style>

    <style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
    </style>
```

> Change your `buildToolsVersion` to `23.0.3`. Then `Sync` your `Gradle` Again.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

> And add this Dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: crashes unfortunately

Comment: Can you tell me where and which crashed ? This settings working for me fine enough.

Comment: yes, of course, the exception is :
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayOptions(int)' on a null object reference`.

the line it crashes at is : `actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); `

Comment: I have a class of ActionBar handler so it causes problems

Comment: For which purpose you have created. You should use `ToolBar` only with `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: @BVtp Make `AppCompatActivity` to `ActionBarActivity` and check. it will work.

Comment: Yes it will not :). Because only work toolbar with `AppCompatActivity`. Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353160/action-bar-not-shown-in-android-studio/37353507#37353507

Comment: so if I use a custom ActionBar I can't use AppCompatActivity?

Comment: @BVtp Nope bro :). You must use `ToolBar` as per Material Design Concept. Appreciate my answer if it is useful to you.

Comment: So basically the use of Activity instead of AppCompatActivity prevents me from using CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: @BVtp Yes as Per New Material design concepts needful to use what i have all suggested thanks :).

Comment: I'm a bit confused.. I need to erase the ActionBar I'm using entirely? and implement a whole new toolbar instead? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112793/discussion-between-jaydroider-and-bvtp).

Comment: If you want to use `Coordinator Layout` and all that then you must need to change. ToolBar` will set dynamic Titles for you for each `Activity`.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work, converting from actionbar to toolbar.. :/

Comment: Changes bit will do the trick for you just follow my answer above which `Link` is provided in comment. and also lots of tutorial are their for dynamic `Tool Bar`.

Comment: Thanks bro for appreciation up-vote it also so it will be helpful to others also thanks :). and let me know if you need any further help good luck :).

Comment: hmmm. This shouldn't be the answer. It didn't solve the issue.

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Extended-ActionBar-Guide
 - here AppCompatActivity is used with ActionBar. How does that work there and in my case it doesn't?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you were wrong.. I was able to leave my ActionBar and use AppCompatActivity. 
All I had to do is change my AcrionBar to support.v7.ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that solved the issue :

1. The activity I was using was extending `Activity`, instead of `AppCompatActivity`, so that had to be changed.
2. However, when changing `Activity` to `AppCompatActivity` I still had crashes because I was using the regular `ActionBar`.
   So the steps I had taken to fix that:

   ```
   a. call `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`
   b. change `ActionBar` to `support.v7.app.ActionBar`
   ```